# How to add an extra column in the response spreadsheet on a Form submit?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have a Google Form with one multiple choices question:

> What do you eat at breakfast?
>
> - Scramble eggs
> - Cereals and milk
> - Sausages
> - Others

The user can select one and only one choice out this.

The problem is that the responses spreadsheet of the Google Form will have only two columns, namely: `Timestamp` and `What do you eat at breakfast?`, and it will store only the result of the choice (`Scramble eggs`, `Cereals and milk`, `Sausages` or `Others`).

What I would like is to have a column `Scramble eggs` with a boolean True/False, a column `Cereals and milk`, and so on. This, in order to ease the usage of markers to create a PDF with checkboxes to display the choice of the user.

For now, I tried several ways to do it, but did not succeed at all... some help would be extremely useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, your text responses are in B2:B. Put "Scrambled Eggs" in C1 and the following formula in C2 (note the empty argument is intentional):

```
=arrayformula(if(isblank(B2:B), , B2:B = C1))
```

This will output nothing when B is blank, and otherwise TRUE or FALSE based on whether the content of B2 matches the value C1. The output will update as new entries come in.

Do the same for Cereals and milk, Sausages or Other.

---

(I do think that scrambled eggs go well with sausage, and you should not restrict users to just one answer. Having separate checkboxes would also avoid this issue.)

Comment: Excellent, I didn't know this `arrayformula()` function! And, yes, next time I'll try to have sausages with my scrambled eggs! :-)